# Nextjs framework.*****.js chunk has high total blocking time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, next.js, web-vitals

In my project I'm measuring performance of next.js and have a high total blocking time.
Typicaly "framework" chunk took more than 50ms multiple times.
From what I've read that this chunk represents react/react-dom js files.
Does it mean that my pages took long time to render/have a lot of rerendering and this is considered as long tasks.
Also, why i have repeatin framework long tasks ?
And how to reduce this total blocking time tasks.
Tech stack of the project

- next.js 13.2.4
- react /react-dom: 18.2.0
- react-query: 3.39.4
- tailwindcss
- typescript.
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was testing the development build instead of the production build. Make sure to use `next build` and `next start` commands.